# Checking a checkbox by Id

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

I am using the following piece of code to check some checkboxes based on their Id and a value stored in a array. So if the array has a value, the corresponding checkbox should become checked.

```
for($k=0;$k<count($array_ids);$k++){
     echo'<script type="text/javascript">

    var cb = document.getElementsById("id_'.$array_ids[$k].'");
    cb.checked = true;

</script>';
}
```

And this is the code for the checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="id_'.$array_ids[$k].'" name="'.$array_ids[$k].'" value="checked" class= "My_class" onchange="add_on_textBox(this,\''.$array_ids[$k].'\',\'My_class\')">
```

And this is the var_dump result for the $array_ids:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Name1"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "Name2"
}
```

The code doesn't work. I am pretty sure I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ID's are unique in a page, there is no plural of `getElementById()`.

You are using `getElementsById()`...remove the `s`.

This should be throwing errors in browser dev tools console also which would give you  clue where the problem is.

Comment: I've removed the s. But there is still a type error: cb is null

Comment: well you may be checking before the elements exist. Is the script after the elements? If not you need a load event handler

Answer (score 0):

You must place the opening and closing `<script>` tags outside the for loop:

```
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">';
    for($k=0;$k<count($array_ids);$k++){


        echo 'var cb = document.getElementsById("id_'.$array_ids[$k].'");
        cb.checked = true;';


    }
    echo '</script>';
```

Comment: is not required. There isn't a limit on script tags. This won't have any impact on code shown